# Matrix equation

Tags: equations, matrices

I'm a new user in texmaker.
How can I produce this equation? Thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please refer to some basic guides of LaTeX, which cover questions like this. For instance, you can find about matrices in section 3.6 of this Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX (https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), or the LaTeX wikipedia.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 14):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
 \begin{bmatrix} \Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ \Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22} \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \frac{1}{\det(X)}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   X_{22} Y_{11} - X_{12} Y_{21} &
   X_{22} Y_{12} - X_{12} Y_{22} \\
   X_{11} Y_{21} - X_{21} Y_{11} &
   X_{11} Y_{22} - X_{21} Y_{12} 
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can try this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12}\\
\Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
=\frac{1}{\det (X)}
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{22} Y_{11} - X_{12} Y_{21} & X_{22} Y_{12} - X_{12} Y_{22}\\
X_{11} Y_{21} - X_{21} Y_{11} & X_{11} Y_{22} - X_{21} Y_{12}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```